# Remove empty {} from end of JSON file

Tags: python, json

My code makes a json request then outputs the data to a json formated file but with empty {} or [] at the end of the file. Here is the code that makes the request:

```
for rt in requestType:
    limit = 1000
    offset = 0
    page = 0
    request = request_str.get(url+rt+'?limit='+str(limit)+'&offset='+str(offset))
    data = request.json()
    total_count = request.headers['X-Total-Count']
    pages = math.ceil(int(total_count) / limit)
    fileName = rt.replace("/","")+".json"
    with open(fileName, 'w') as outf:
        json.dump(data, outf,  indent=4)
    while (page) < pages:
        offset = offset + limit
        request = request_str.get(url+rt+'?limit='+str(limit)+'&offset='+str(offset))
        data = request.json()
        with open(fileName, 'a') as outf:
            json.dump(data, outf,  indent=4)
        page += 1
```

Here is an example of the json file:

```
{
    "orgs": [
        {
            "sourcedId": "04EB8C87-7B48-474A-9404-4E352FE3207E",
            "status": "active",
            "dateLastModified": "2020-06-25T19:51:00.000Z",
            "name": "name of org",
            "type": "building",
            "identifier": "0157",
        }
    ]
},{
    "orgs": []
}
```

How can I remove the `{"orgs": []}` from the end of the file? Or better yet, how can I prevent this from getting written to the file in the first place?

Comment: What would the page's json possibly look like? e.g. {}, {"org":[]}? Do you want the "org" combine together?

Answer (score 0):

Add logic that only write if the length of the data is greater than 0:

```
for rt in requestType:
    limit = 1000
    offset = 0
    page = 0
    request = request_str.get(url+rt+'?limit='+str(limit)+'&offset='+str(offset))
    data = request.json()
    total_count = request.headers['X-Total-Count']
    pages = math.ceil(int(total_count) / limit)
    fileName = rt.replace("/","")+".json"
    with open(fileName, 'w') as outf:
        json.dump(data, outf,  indent=4)
    while (page) < pages:
        offset = offset + limit
        request = request_str.get(url+rt+'?limit='+str(limit)+'&offset='+str(offset))
        data = request.json()
        if len(data['orgs']) > 0:     #<-- if data len greater than 0, append it
            with open(fileName, 'a') as outf:
                json.dump(data, outf,  indent=4)
        page += 1
```

Comment: I added the line to check the length and I'm still getting the empty element at the end of the file. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: ah, thats because you need to check the values in the data keys. I edited above. see if that did the trick. its tough to debug though without knowing what your `data` returns from the requests. it may throw an error if `'orgs'` is not always in your json response

Comment: This works to remove `orgs` but if the end of the file contains `{ [] }`, it errors, as you mentioned could happen. So how can this be handled?

Comment: theoretically you shouldn't get that as it's not a valid json format. There would need to be a key with the value of an empty list, Ie `{'some_key': [])` Is it possible you'll get a key other than 'orgs'?

Comment: Will there always be in the form of `{'some_key':[{'some_data':'value'}]}`. Because then ya, we can simply just take in any key and check if it's len is > 0. If the json though sometimes returns nested data, that'll get tricky

Answer (score 0):

suppose first request and the page requests have similar format of data

e.g. **{"org":[...]}**

how about merge their "orgs" list before writing to json file?

```
    ......
    pages = math.ceil(int(total_count) / limit)
    while (page) < pages:
        offset = offset + limit
        request = request_str.get(url+rt+'?limit='+str(limit)+'&offset='+str(offset))
        
        tdata = request.json()                       # new buffer
        try:
            data['orgs'] = data['orgs'] + tdata['orgs']  # merge orgs
        except Exception:
            pass
        page += 1

    # lastly, save it to json
    fileName = rt.replace("/","")+".json"
    with open(fileName, 'w') as outf:
        json.dump(data, outf,  indent=4)
```